# Is there an analog method that can be used to amplify magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there an analog amplification method which can be used with magnetic fields similar to electrical signal amplifiers like those made of heated cathode vacuum tubes?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an iron core to a current-carrying coil increases the magnetic flux density inside the coil greatly compared with its value if there were just air inside the coil. But maybe this isn't what you meant!

*Magnetic amplifiers* may be the devices you are seeking. The idea is that you can drastically reduce the inductance of a coil wound on an iron core by magnetically near-saturating the core, using dc passed through another coil. Hence you can control the alternating current through the first coil by adjusting the direct current through the other. That's the gist of it. Read more on the internet!

Comment: I'm aiming more for a volumetric/planar amplification than a single sensor - or a bunch of single sensors I could DIY into a matrix with pretty good resolution like pixels on a screen.  My goal is to couple an amplifier to a [ferrocell](https://www.ferrocell.us/buy%20complete%20systems.html) along with some lenses (those I believe I can make as metamaterials out of combinations of ferromagnetic and paramagnetic materials) to build a magnetic telescope.  My ideal would be something tubular wherein one side is exposed to weak magnetic fields and the other side has them amplified.

Comment: I'm beginning to get the picture, but unfortunately I can't suggest anything that would help. There is, of course, the clumsy and no doubt impracticable solution of amplifying Hall probe voltages and using the amplified signals to drive electromagnets.

Answer (score 2):

Philip Wood is right. to enlarge slightly: years ago, magnetic amplifiers were actually used in certain special applications in electronics- particularly, automatic control systems- at a time when other more convenient means had not yet been invented.

As another example: it is possible to use air flow and pressure in pipes to control other airflows in automatic machinery- and to hence build (very rudimentary) digital computers out of little dinguses that operated entirely on compressed air. This so-called *air logic* disappeared when electronic logic got cheap.